# Azure function created by Java is saying "Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file" , how to resolve it?

Tags: java, azure, serverless

Currently, I'm working on Azure function created by Java. I am able to publish Java function to Azure portal and I'm able to make a GET and POST request but I'm having issue with enabling function in write mode. So, what I am supposed to do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior when your function app is deployed in **Run From Package** mode, which means it's reading the files directly from the uploaded ZIP and so there's no way to edit it.

You can turn that off by deleting the **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** application setting in the portal.

Note: This will clear your function app until the next time you publish if you delete the setting.

For more details, Please check [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I was thinking that if I can enable function in write mode then I can configure input and output trigger from Azure portal. Now, I have found some other ways to manage the input and output operations from Azure functions.